# Using Nginx and Apache to serve web application

Tags: django, apache, nginx, wsgi

I have a number of PHP sites running on Apache, however I am about to launch my first Django site.
I have successfully got WSGI working on Apache to handle the Python scripts but I am a bit stuck with using Nginx to serve my media files.

I know I need to make Apache listen on a different port and get Nginx to listen on port 80, then forward any non-media requests to Apache on port 8080.

What I really want to know is, is there an easy way to configure it to work with all of my existing sites or do I need to set up a separate record for every one of my current sites just to forward the requests to port 8080?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to use Nginx? Apache can serve the media files too.

Comment: I don't need to, but I am trying to follow the recommended guidelines in the documentation

Comment: Are you looking to use nginx as a reverse proxy for apache or just as a media server?

Comment: I just want to use it to serve static files in my Django applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down a bit in the [Django documentation about serving static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-media-files), they give you the information on how to make Apache serve the files for you so that you don't need nginx (assumes your media files are in `/usr/local/wsgi/static/media/`):

```
Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/wsgi/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /usr/local/wsgi/static/favicon.ico

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /usr/local/wsgi/static/styles/$1

Alias /media/ /usr/local/wsgi/static/media/

<Directory /usr/local/wsgi/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/django.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local/wsgi/scripts>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If, however, you are dead set on using nginx, you would add your static directives in your `server {}` directive:

```
location /media/ {
    access_log off; # who cares about static files?
    alias /usr/local/wsgi/static/media/;
    expires 30d; # enables caching.
}
```